# Excel VBA - How to use the For Each...Next statement

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently learning VBA by doing, and I'm trying to understand the syntax of the For Each...Next statement. If the syntax is:

```
For Each element In group
[statements]
[Exit For]
[statements]
Next [element]
```

What sort of variables can you use for "element" and "group", and do you define them? I ask because most of the examples I've found for the function don't define "element".

Say I have a column full of "a", "b", "c", "d" and "N/A", and I want to determine the number of times each appear in the column.

So far I have the following:

```
Sub Count()

Dim lastRow, aCount, bCount, cCount, dCount, NACount As Long

lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
aCount = 0
bCount = 0
cCount = 0
dCount = 0
NACount = 0

For Each MyCell In Range("A1:A" & lastRow)
    If MyCell.Value = "a" Then
        aCount = aCount + 1
    ElseIf MyCell.Value = "b" Then
        bCount = bCount + 1
    ElseIf MyCell.Value = "c" Then
        cCount = cCount + 1
    ElseIf MyCell.Value = "d" Then
        dCount = dCount + 1
    ElseIf MyCell.Value = "b" Then
        bCount = bCount + 1
    Else
        NACount = NACount + 1
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

This give a "Type mismatch" error for `If MyCell.Value = "a" Then`, though I already know that I must be using a wrong group or array.

Any help for such a beginner issue is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the error isn't "Variable not defined?" (assuming you're using `Option Explicit` at the top of your code modules, which you *should*)  You do need to declare the loop variable (in your case `MyCell`)

Comment: code raises a mismatch if `MyCell` contains an Error value.

Comment: Have you tried F1 Help? Because it says in there what *element* and *group* can be.

Comment: dim mycell as range !!!! and at the end : next mycell

Comment: @TimWilliams I've just learned about how to make variables defining mandatory, will use that from now on

Comment: @Jean-Fran&#231;oisCorbett I use the Help library with every occasion, but I'm still wrapping my head around data types. In this case, I wasn't sure if I was correctly calling the range, and how exatly the function was using the element.

Comment: @DavidZemens I assume N/A caused the error value in this case, as I understood from yoir answer below

Comment: @PatrickLepelletier If declaring the element at the end is optional, how would this help the function?

Comment: @Dirk101 `#N/A` certainly would raise an error. If the answer has solved your question/problem, please mark it as "accepted".  Cheers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First things first:

> Say I have a column full of "a", "b", "c", "d" and "N/A", and I want to determine the number of times each appear in the column.

You **should** just use the `CountIf` function :)

But as a learning exercise... Your code is raising an error most likely because of an "Error" value in the sheet/cell being counted.

You could fix it like

```
If Cstr(MyCell.Value) = "a"...
```

Make sure to do this for the other conditionals, too, or you could do something like:

```
For Each myCell In Range("A1:A" & lastRow)
Dim clVal As String
clVal = CStr(myCell)
    If clVal = "a" Then
        aCount = aCount + 1
    ElseIf clVal = "b" Then
        bCount = bCount + 1
    ElseIf clVal = "c" Then
        cCount = cCount + 1
    ElseIf clVal = "d" Then
        dCount = dCount + 1
    ElseIf clVal = "b" Then
        bCount = bCount + 1
    Else
        NACount = NACount + 1
    End If
Next
```

**WHY**

Because `MyCell` is undeclared, it can be an error type.  You can't do a string comparison of an error and a string, so that's raising the Type Mismatch error.  You can use the `CStr` function to cast `MyCell.Value` as a string and that can avoid the error.

**A note on declaring your variables...**

You should declare ALL of your variables and type them appropriately. VBA does not support multiple implicit inline declarations like:

`Dim lastRow, aCount, bCount, cCount, dCount, NACount As Long`

This is functionaly equivalent to:

```
Dim lastRow   'As Variant
Dim aCount    'As Variant
Dim bCount    'As Variant
Dim cCount    'As Variant
Dim dCount    'As Variant
Dim naCount As Long
```

Which is probably not what you were expecting. Instead, do:

`Dim lastRow as Long, aCount as Long, bCount as Long, _
    cCount as Long, dCount as Long, NACount As Long`

You should also declare ALL of your variables, always, including your loop iterators, like `MyCell`.  One way to enforce this is to always put `Option Explicit` at the top of your module. This forces variable declaration, and as such, raises a compile error if you have misspelled variable name somewhere, etc. (this is super-common, actually, so always use Option Explicit!, it will save you a lot of hair-pulling).

Loop iterators can be of type `Variant` or they must match a type that is iterable in the collection/array, e.g.:

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
For each ws in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Debug.Print ws.Name
Next
```

Or they can be a long/integer for an indexed collection

```
Dim w as Integer
For w = 1 to ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    Debug.Print w
Next
```

Also, review the documentation:

**[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264596(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264596%28v=office.15%29.aspx)**

Ultimately what method you use to iterate depends on what you're trying to accomplish and the structures of the data you're working with.

Comment: Placing `Dim clVal...` inside the `For` loop is missleading, as it might suggest that it is only valid inside the loop. While _some_ languages would limit the scope of `clVal` to the `For` loop, this is not the case for VBA.  Once that line has executed once, the variable remains valid and available until the routine completes.

Comment: @chrisneilsen a variable can generally be declared *anywhere* in a subroutine in VBA and this variable would be available even *before* that line "executes" for the simple fact that this line doesn't "execute" (step through the code using F8 to confirm...) . For brevity's sake I put it inside that loop but in practice I would put all my declarations at the top of the module. I just didn't want to rewrite the entire thing and try to explain it *all* to someone who clearly does not know even the basics of VBA -- it's much easier to just explain a small block.

Comment: I didn't say your code was _wrong_ (wouldn't work) I said it was _missleading_ for the reasons given, and I stand by that.  Your claim that a `Dim` can go _anywhere_ is not correct. When declared as a `Sub`/`Function` scoped variable, it must go before the variable is referenced.    And you arn't declaring _all_ your variables as _module_ scope, are you?

Comment: @chrisneilsen you're correct about the variable must be declared before it's referenced (although in debug mode this is not the case...). I still think you're picking nits on the `For` loop.  The only people who might be "misled" by this are those with enough programming experience to read the documentation and troubleshoot apparent oddities on their own.

Comment: I was almost certain to have written a comment for your answer when I first read it. In any case, thank you for your thorough reply. I may be VBA illiterate, but your answer was actually of help in furthering my understanding, though you may make a point that at my level anything is of help. I'll look into CountIf and see how to use it best for my ends.